# Rename File open by self

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file-io

My program is logging data to a file, at the same time a user interface displays the incoming data live. I want the logged data to be on disk within a second or two if computer/program/os/whatever shuts down. Data is coming in at least 100 times/sec.

I want the user to be able to give the log-file a new name, while logging is active. The problem is that i can't change the name of the file while it is open, even if it is by the same process.

Test case:

```
string fileName1 = "test.txt";
string fileName2 = "test2.txt";

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(fileName1, FileMode.Create)))
{
     sw.WriteLine("before");
     File.Move(fileName1, fileName2);  //<<-- IOException - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
     w.WriteLine("after");
 }
```

So, **How do i rename a file from a process while the same process is having a stream to the file open?**

Comment: If you're logging that much data, you really should try a logging library like log4net (http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Comment: unfortunately, you can not move the file or change its name or even delete it when you are using its stream, it is just like if it in use by another program...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should close the first stream, rename the file, then reopen the stream:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(fileName1, FileMode.Create)))
{
  sw.WriteLine("before");
  sw.Close();
}

File.Move(fileName1, fileName2);

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(fileName2, FileMode.Append)))
{
  sw.WriteLine("after");
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work, because you can not set the `sw` while it is in the using block. Error: `Cannot assign to 'sw' because it is a 'using variable'`

Comment: Sounds reasonable. But you must mean filename2 the second time, and the filemode can't be create right? As long as i lock any logging during the gap while i don't have any stream i guess this would work.

Comment: Ok, i was hoping for a more elegant solution but i guess this will do. Marking as answer

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is a bit late to help you on your porting project but perhaps it will help others!

If you open the file with the [`FileShare.Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) flag it will let you rename it even though it is still open :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't rename a file while it is open by a process, but if you want to write to it from the other instance of your program, do this.

Try [FileShare.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx).  You can use it in [File.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx).

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter (File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)) 
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening en closing the file 100 times a second will have a impact on your performance, you can log to a temp file and append the temp file every 10 seconds or so. That will give you what you want.

Comment: File is open during the whole time the program is running. Renaming might only happen once or twice iniated by the user.

Comment: If you want to rename the file, it should not be open. So only opening it once every 10 seconds to append log entries enables the user to rename the file while the program runs.